# How many partitions when reading parquet data from Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parquet

I'm using Spark 1.6.0. and DataFrame API for reading partitioned parquet data.

I'm wondering how many partitions will be used.

Here are some figures on my data :

- 2182 files
- 196 partitions
- 2 GB

It seems that Spark uses 2182 partitions because when I perform a `count`, the job is splitted into 2182 tasks.

That's seem to be confirmed by `df.rdd.partitions.length`

Is that correct ? In all cases ?

If yes, is it too high regarding the volume of data (i.e. should I use `df.repartition` to reduce it) ?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can use the re-partition method to reduce the number of tasks such that it is in balance with available resources. you also need to define the number of executor per node, no. of nodes and memory per node while submitting the app so that the tasks will execute in parallel and utilise maximum resources.